# CakePHP 3 - conditional saving of data in associated table

Tags: mysql, forms, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

I have the following tables:

- Bookings (hasOne Sessions)
- Sessions (hasOne Guest Staff)
- Guest Staff

In my form, I have input fields designated as follows:

- For Bookings related fields, their form input's ID is in the form of `name`.
- For Sessions related fields, their form input's ID is in the form of `session.name`.
- For Guest Staff related fields, their form input's ID is in the form `session.gueststaff.name`.

However, not all Sessions have Guest Staff, and so I want to only create a newEntity for and save data to Guest Staff on submission only if their fields are filled in. Currently, when I attempt a submission with Guest Staff inputs filled in, the save works fine. But when I attempt a form submit without any Guest Staff inputs being filled, the save fails.

A debug of $save in the Controller just gave me this: `false`, which isn't very helpful.

Looking through the POST data, the Guest Staff array is in the form of this (basically empty):

```
Guest Staff {
    firstname: 
    lastname:    
}
```

I then attempted to remove the Not Null requirement in MySQL, and then re-Cake Bake the Guest Staff model. However, when I tried to resubmit the form after this, while the form was able to save, a new data entry was still created in the Guest Staff table, with just an ID and the foreign key that connected it to Sessions, while the other fields were blank, which isn't what I want, as that would mean there would be a lot of useless data entries in that table.

**Update:** As per Manohar Khadka's suggestion, I have added an if statement and unset.

Currently in controller:

```
public function add()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $data = $this->request->data;
            if(empty($data['session']['gueststaff']['firstname'])){
                unset($data['session']['gueststaff']);
                $booking = $this->Bookings->newEntity([
                    'associated' => [
                        'Sessions'
                    ]
                ]);
            } else {
                $booking = $this->Bookings->newEntity([
                    'associated' => [
                        'Sessions', 'Sessions.Gueststaff'
                    ]
                ]);
            }
            $booking = $this->Bookings->patchEntity($booking, $data, [
                'associated' => [
                    'Sessions', 'Sessions.Gueststaff'
                ]
            ]);
            $save = $this->Bookings->save($booking);
            if ($save) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The booking was successfully completed.'));
                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'bookings', 'action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('Unfortunately, the booking could not be completed. Please try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
```

And my form:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($booking) ?>
<legend><?= __('Session Details') ?></legend>
<?= $this->Form->input('session.location', ['class' => 'form-control']); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('session.date', ['class' => 'form-control']); ?>                     

<h6>Warning: Fill in the following Guest Staff details if a Guest Staff member will be present.</h6>
<?= $this->Form->input('session.gueststaff.firstname', ['class' => 'form-control']); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('session.gueststaff.lastname', ['class' => 'form-control']); ?>

<?= $this->Form->button('<strong>' . __('Complete Session Details') . '</strong>', ['id' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']); ?>

<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Comment: I tried the same without look, and opted for adding the optional data on another form, but you can check them on edit and add methods, with $this->request->data then you can unset the entity if it is empty (before patchEntity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can better handle these things form [Callbacks](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#lifecycle-callbacks) method like beforeSave.

Or you can simply check if fields are empty in saving method such as:

```
public function add()
{
    $booking = $this->Bookings->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = $this->request->data;
        if(empty($data['session']['gueststaff']['firstname'])){
            unset($data['session']['gueststaff']);
            $booking = $this->Bookings->patchEntity($booking, $data, [
                'associated' => [
                    'Sessions'
                ]
            ]);
        } else {
            $booking = $this->Bookings->patchEntity($booking, $data, [
                'associated' => [
                    'Sessions', 'Sessions.Gueststaff'
                ]
            ]);
        }
        $save = $this->Bookings->save($booking);
        if ($save) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The booking was successfully completed.'));
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'bookings', 'action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unfortunately, the booking could not be completed. Please try again.'));
        }
       // $this->set(compact('booking'));
    }
}
```

When making above logic I suppose input field name like this:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('gueststaff.fname');?> //<input type="text" name="gueststaff[fname]">
<?= $this->Form->input('gueststaff.lname');?>
```

And You can do these things from client side if you wish.

Comment: When I put the creation of `newEntity` after `$this->request->is('post')`, on the View itself it says that `$booking` is undefined. In my View, `$this->Form->create($booking)` is what starts the form, with $booking referring to what was the creation of the `newEntity` prior to POST. How should I refer to $booking now since `newEntity` creation is moved after POST?

Comment: Well it will be more clear if you update your question with your form and saving method.

Comment: Added it to the OP.

Comment: Things looks good..I have managed little things..Please see the updated answer !